# How to swap order of div element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How do i change the order of div elements which includes textbox and dropdown with angular's data binding?. The order of div should change accordingly users login means if user type is A then div A should be on top, if user type is B then div B should be on top and other div elements will below that and so on..  The app is purely made in AngularJS.

Here's HTML:

```
<div id="A"> A <input type="text" ng-model="Model.AName" disabled /></div>
<div id="B"> B <input type="text" ng-model="Model.BName" disabled /></div>
<div id="C"> C <input type="text" ng-model="Model.CName" disabled /></div>
```

In AngularJS Controller:

```
 $scope.orderArr = [{ "A": 2}, { "B": 3 }, { "C": 1 }];
```

Result will be:
C
A
B

Comment: The user type is `C` ?

Comment: The A, B, and C are user types like SuperAdmin, Admin, and User etc.

Comment: Does orderArr need to be like this, or can it be changed to `[{ type: "A", order: 2}, {type: "B", order: 3}, {type: "C", order: 1}]`. This would make it less complicated.

Comment: @JanP order is not necessary like this.

Comment: @HarshalY Actually, I do think it is necessary, as you need something to order by. Have a look at Jarek's answer.

Comment: @JanP  Yes, that order makes the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manage order you have to create array represent inputs.

```
$scope.inputs = [
  {
    name: 'AName',
    order: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'BName',
    order: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'CName',
    order: 0
  }
];
```

And then display it using a loop:

```
<div id="A" ng-repeat="input in inputs | orderBy: 'order'">
  {{ input.name }}
  <input type="text" disabled ng-model="Model[input.name]">
</div>
```

In this way you can manage the order in your controller by changing the property `order`.
You can create conditional statements, which depending on the Permission set the order of your inputs.

Comment: This makes the sense! But what i needed is there are multiple input text and dropdown's that i have to bind data accordingly, how?

Comment: See on input's ng-model, you can bind variables by property `name`.