# Change element order from controller angularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

Hello so if some variable exists (token within) I want to change 2 divs order - turn them other way around, from controller.

I found [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439228/how-to-swap-order-of-div-element-in-angularjs#answer-41439391) to do this with `ng-repeat` directive but I don't really want to use `ng-repeat` in this case because I already have many `ng-repeat`s in this two divs and I think it may cause some problems, maybe even longer loading.

Is there any other way to change divs order from controller? Maybe I can just add some classes to elements whenever variable exists or not, if I remember good I can change elements order with flexbox help.

Could you guys show me path how to accomplish this task? I would be grateful
if you provide some little demo.

Comment: `ng-repeat` is a fine solution, it is a bad practice to manipulate the DOM from a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody answered my question which I already have found solution for. Someone in comment section said that I should use `ng-repeat` because it's good solution but I could not really figure out how to use it and keep tone of html content inside those 2 divs. I don't want to bind all of it from controller, do I?

So what I did instead is wrap this 2 divs inside another div with `display: flex` and then used `ng-class` directive on this 2 divs inside new container to dynamically add classes with this rules:

**1st div**

```
.flex-container--child_1 {
    order:2;
}
```

**2nd div**

```
.flex-container--child_2 {
    order:1;
 }
```

The `ng-class` add this two classes to divs whenever some variable exist like I wanted.

```
<div ng-class="{'flex-container--child_1': authentication.isAuth}">...</div>
```

I wrote this post if somebody ever came across same problem and find this question on SO.